# typeof XService is not assignable to type 'FactoryProvider'. Property 'provide' is missing

Tags: angular, ionic2, pouchdb

I have an Angular 2 `NgModule` in a Ionic 2 mobile app defined like so:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
  ],
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, VatRatesDbService]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and the service defined this way:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

@Injectable()
export class VatRatesDbService {

  private _db;

  private constructor() {
    this._db = new PouchDB('rates.db', { adapter: 'websql' });
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error at runtime:

> Type 'typeof VatRatesDbService' is not assignable to type
>   'FactoryProvider'. Property 'provide' is missing in type 'typeof
>   VatRatesDbService'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to remove the **private modifier** from the constructor. You simply cannot have an injectable service with a private constuctor.

```
public constructor() {
  this._db = new PouchDB('rates.db', { adapter: 'websql' });
}
```

or:

```
constructor() {
  this._db = new PouchDB('rates.db', { adapter: 'websql' });
}
```

Answer (score 41):

It happens because of ionic latest update for ionic 4.

You have to import it like this (adding '/ngx' )

```
import { PluginName} from '@ionic-native/pluginName/ngx';
```

Or, you can downgrade the plugin's version

It was happening to me with another plugin.

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375185/type-httporiginal-is-not-assignable-to-type-provider-ionic-error-after-plugin-i)

Comment: This exactly fixed my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So simple ty! :)

Answer (score 2):

It work for me In Ionic 4

You have to import it like this (adding '/ngx' )

import { PluginName} from '@ionic-native/pluginName/ngx';

Answer (score 0):

**[Source Link](http://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-create-ionic-v3-app-in-latest-cli-v4-9-0-for-ionic-v4/)**

I am facing this issue in latest Ionic 4 CLI version 4.9.0

When I created older version Ionic 3 application in latest CLI and installed Native plugin **App Version** I faced this error

***[ts]
Type 'AppVersionOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Type 'AppVersionOriginal' is missing the following properties from type 'FactoryProvider': provide, useFactory [2322]***

for that, we need to install an older version of the native plugin