# Type 'SQLiteOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'

Tags: ionic4

I'm new to Ionic 4 and am trying to get SQLite working. I have added the cordova plugin and the ionic native sqlite but when I try and set it up in the app module I get the above error. Here is my app,module.ts

```
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), IonicStorageModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    SQLite,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to import from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx'

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this has to do with the recent release of Ionic 4.  I ran into this issue with `@ionic-native/file` within my app.  If you installed after the release without specifying the version you wanted, you probably got the latest or beta version.

I was able to fix it by rolling back to an earlier version by modifying my `package.json` to reflect the version required -- I had `5.0.0` installed and rolled back to `4.20.0`.  If you have VersionLens for VSCode it will show you the minimum and the latest versions.

Then, clear your node modules, and reinstall:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

There is another post open this, available here:

[Type HTTPOriginal is not assignable to type Provider, ionic error after plugin installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375185/type-httporiginal-is-not-assignable-to-type-provider-ionic-error-after-plugin-i)

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I added the /ngx in the import and that has fixed it

Comment: Indeed. That also worked for me! Tip: You may probably mark an answer, as it will be easier to find the solution for other developers in te future.

Answer (score 3):

It happens because of the new update of ionic 4.

You have to add /ngx to your plugin's import. Like this:

```
import { PluginName} from '@ionic-native/pluginName/ngx';
```

Otherwise fallback to ionic v4.

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375185/type-httporiginal-is-not-assignable-to-type-provider-ionic-error-after-plugin-i)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint, you have saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere where native plugins are imported, you need to add /ngx/.

Moreover, this must be done throughout the project, otherwise the error will still appear.

**Error example:**

```
import {Market} from '@ionic-native/market';
```

**True example:**

```
import {Market} from '@ionic-native/market/ngx';
```

Answer (score 0):

Import:

```
import { SQLitePorter } from '@ionic-native/sqlite-porter/ngx';
import { SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';
```

And add into provider:

```
providers: [
   SQLite,
   SQLitePorter
]
```

This usually happens if you import them from different path.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx' at both  app.module.ts and the page you want to use it.