# Type 'AppVersionOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'. Type 'AppVersionOriginal' is missing the following properti

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic4

I have created new Ionic 3 application using the latest version of Ionic CLI v4.9.0  using below

```
$ ionic start Ionic3Project blank --type ionic-angular
```

which create V4 Ionic project by default.

Then I followed steps for Native App Version Plugin [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/app-version/)

Faced following console error when imported in **app.module.ts** file

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'AppModule' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [StatusBar, ?[object Object]?, ...]
at syntaxError (compiler.js:486)
at compiler.js:15784
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15752)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15320)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34413)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34374)
at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34268)
at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:239)
at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5578)
```

**app.module.ts** file

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
    import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
    import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version';

    import { MyApp } from './app.component';
    import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
      ],
      bootstrap: [IonicApp],
      entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage
      ],
      providers: [
        StatusBar,
        AppVersion, <-- Error [[ts]
                                Type 'AppVersionOriginal' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
                                Type 'AppVersionOriginal' is missing the following properties from type 'FactoryProvider': provide, useFactory [2322]]
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

**UPDATE:Finally I found solution and explanation of this issue [here](https://www.freakyjolly.com/how-to-create-ionic-v3-app-in-latest-cli-v4-9-0-for-ionic-v4/) :P**

Comment: Also encoutenred this issue when upgrading the `@ionic-native/app-version` package. I switched back to the previous version I was using : `npm i --save @ionic-native/app-version@4.18.0`

Answer (score 6):

This issue is because of ionic new update(releasing ionic 4)
You have to import your plugins for ionic 3 like this:

```
import { PluginName} from '@ionic-native/pluginName/ngx';
```

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54375185/type-httporiginal-is-not-assignable-to-type-provider-ionic-error-after-plugin-i)

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown because of the new update of ionic 4.
The above given solution would work perfectly.

But, this must be done throughout the project to avoid this error.
The other way could be to roll back to plugin's previous version.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Tried, but can't as I don't have enough rep.